# SVN Hook does not have write permissions

Tags: svn, hook, post-commit

I have successfully set up a post-commit script that can send e-mails and whatever.

I extended it to, on commit, checkout the newly committed repo locally and run doxygen on it.
I have an issue with permissions though. When I do a commit (which is mapped through HTTP), my post-commit log says permission denied for both checking out and running doxygen.

I have set file ownership of the local working copy to the same as the post-commit hook script is, so I would have thought when SVN can execute the post-commit script it would be able to likewise manipulate it.

How do I grant write access for subversion, so that my post-commit can do things like  generate documentation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember what is running the svn program. If you are running this through your HTTP, then whatever user your web server is running as will run the svn. This means that **www-data, apache, or another web server user must have write permissions** on the directories you want to write to.

Usually, I create a temp directory named after the pid ($$ in the post-commit bash script) and then do all of my work in there.